# How to remove or hide component in Pelle C IDE

Tags: c, pelles-c

I want to remove or hide some components from my window (button, combobox, etc). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found answer on pelles-c forum: http://forum.pellesc.de/index.php?topic=6382.0

```
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
// where hWnd - is some component
```